# Связь через ForeignObject с моделью из соседнего приложения

Tags: python, база-данных, django, django-orm

Как можно реализовать ForeignObject с моделью из соседнего приложения?

У меня есть проект, в нем 2 приложения. Условно app1 и app2. В app1 есть модель для групп. А в app2 модель для клиентов, каждый из которых принадлежит какой либо группе. Так вот, как мне связать юзера с группой?

Пробывал так: (project/app2/models.py)

```
from app1.models import Group

class Client(Model):
    group = ForeignObject(Groups, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Данный код выдаёт ошибку:

```
group = models.ForeignObject(Groups, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'from_fields' and 'to_fields'
```

Не смог найти что и как нужно передавать в 'from_fields' и 'to_fields'. Нашел только что через to_fields можно указать какое поле станет ключевым (по умолчанию это pk), но в каком виде мне его туда передать - нет.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db import models


class Client(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```